# deploying django app with gunicorn and nginx

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx, gunicorn, ubuntu-16.04

Okay so I have been working on this for awhile now and I know many people have had similar problems to myself but I can't seem to find the right solution.

Anyway I have followed the tutorial exactly as laid out on Digital Ocean

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

everything works fine when I test gunicorn with

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi:application
```

however when I create a systemd file and try to create a proxy pass with nginx I receive a 502 bad gateway error.

when I run:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

I get error message:

```
15:18:39 [crit] 10558#10558: *1 connect() to unix:/home/bmhinformatics/Desktop/ProvCaRe/ProvCaRe.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream
```

my gunicorn systemd file looks like:

/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=sammy
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/usr/myproject
ExecStart=/home/usr/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind    unix:/home/usr/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and my nginx proxypass file looks like:

/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name server_domain_or_IP;

  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  location /static/ {
      root /home/usr/myproject;
  }

  location / {
      include proxy_params;
      proxy_pass http://unix:/home/sammy/myproject/myproject.sock;
  }
}
```

I can't seem to identify the error.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Also when I look in my project directory where the files are pointing there is no myproject.sock file

Comment: I doubt very much that you have a Desktop directory on your production server, so that part of the configuration is wrong at least.

Comment: Daniel, I do have a desktop on my production server.  However I have moved my project and I am still getting an  16:23:22 [crit] 11975#11975: *1 connect() to unix:/home/bmhinformatics/ProvCaRe/ProvCaRe.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream